# How can I proof if payment was successful?

Tags: php, paypal, payment, feedback

I want to build a simple PayPal express check-out system.
On my page are two products I offer which should be able to directly be purchased (without registration). After paying the user should get an email with an individual generated code for a streaming content.

How do I realize that?

Comment: Yes there's lots of tutorials on paypal.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar recently and I found the best way was with a combination of PayPal's "upload cart" function, and PayPal's IPN callback. Relevant links;

[Tool to generate a "Buy Now" button](https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_shoppingcart-intro-outside) <- easily modified for a cart upload using the next link

[Variables for cart upload form](https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_std-variable-ref-cart-upload.html)

[PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Nofitication) documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) <- you can set the IPN URL as a variable on the upload cart form as well, PayPal will immediately call on this URL, passing relevant data, upon checkout completion

Using the above you can upload several items to a cart in one click, you can also include custom data that will get passed back to you via the IPN call. That should be enough to get you started.